# JavaScript forms on the fly, no HTML forms

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal, jquery-plugins

I am trying to build a web application that will take an scan paper form and in top of it I will be able to add text boxes using JavaScript like jQuery that later on I can use to fill the form and print it as PDF or email it.

My question is about the JavaScript, is there any existing library that will allow me to to drag and drop text boxes (note I don't want a text field) and that will remember its location?

The forms will have a lot of fields that and the forms will change a lot from one to another that is why I am not converting the forms into regular HTML forms. For the backend I plan to use Drupal in LAMP, so jQuery is included already.

Thank you.

Note: I still don't understand why this question was close, but just for reference in case someone has a similar question the solution was to use the jquery annotate image pluging. By using this plugging I was able to click anywhere in the image and add text to it. I also have to make some changes so that it can also show the anotatations without waiting for the mouse over.

Comment: I think they want to have forms be placed at absoulte positions via javascript.  It sounds like this would be much easier if they used a java applet.

Comment: Sometimes it worries me that I seem to be able to understand things pretty clearly that don't make any sense to other people.

Comment: @LarryLustig, I agree. The question made sense to me.

Comment: I don't know why the question was close when it is a legit question. I am just trying to see if there is an existing JavaScript library to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  This is a perfectly reasonable beginner jQuery (or other javascript library) question.  And an interesting one, too.  Maybe not perfectly clear, but clear enough that it's easily and specifically answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use JQuery [drag and drop](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/), YUI [drag and drop](https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/dd/) or other libraries to drag around dom elements, including form fields.

But you will still need to write a good amount of software to create a working application.

Depending on your skill level, the amount of work will either be doable or you'll need to hire a programmer... Good luck.

**Added** Re: remembering the location of the fields. When you get a "drag ended" event, you can query the library to find out the current location of the field that was dragged. At that point, you'd probably use Ajax to store/update the field's new location in your database, on your server.

You may also want to check out FormAssembly, Mufoo and other form packages to see if you can use your own background (the scanned image) for the form.

Comment: position can be remembered inside a cookie and the form can be serialized and then stored per ajax request.

Comment: @hakre, agreed. Could also use a "Save" button or asynchronously save using html 5 local storage. Lots of options.

Comment: I am planning to store the field with their positions in a serialize array in MySQL and then use it to rebuild the fillable form when ready. I didn't think of local storage, but it is another nice alternative as well.

Comment: @redhatlab, I suggest you try the Google docs User Experience--use ajax to save the updated form in the background with a "Save Now" button and "Saved momements ago (or whatever) feedback message.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want this designer-like function of locating text boxes as overlays on images to work in the browser — your application is the designer, not the ultimate form filler?

Check out [jQuery draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) to accomplish the moving around.  You'll need to persist the layout yourself, but it shouldn't be hard.  You can do it with a Save button, or you can actual use the Stop() event defined by draggable and persist changes as they happen.

Comment: The application should be both the form designer and the form filler.